# LiveSDK for Universal Windows App background upload

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app, live-sdk

I'm developing Universal Windows App and use Live SDK 5.6 to upload files to OneDrive. I see examples of usage [here](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-Windows) and instructions about versions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn659730.aspx).
According to instructions I should use:

For Windows and WP81: `CreateBackgroundUploadAsync` method;

For WP8 Silverlight: `BackgroundUploadAsync` method

`CreateBackgroundUploadAsync` works like a charm on Windows and returns correct progress values by `LiveOperationProgress` but on a WP81 it shows 0% progress all the time and at last it becames 100%. So it actually does not track progress.

Then I tried to use `BackgroundUploadAsync`(it is for Silverlight apps) and it works on phone - uploads file and tracks progress right. But when I tried to upload big file(in my case > 150Mb) I noted that exactly after 120 seconds upload operation just resets to 0% and starts again without any exceptions.

Here is code for Windows & WP81 approach:

```
var progressHandler = new Progress<LiveOperationProgress>(
                    (progress) =>
                    {
                        var res = progress.ProgressPercentage;
                    });
LiveUploadOperation uploadOperation = await liveConnectClient.CreateBackgroundUploadAsync(uploadPath, "testfile.wav", file, OverwriteOption.Rename);
LiveOperationResult uploadResult = await uploadOperation.StartAsync(new CancellationToken(), progressHandler);
```

And for Silverlight:

```
var progressHandler = new Progress<LiveOperationProgress>(
                    (progress) =>
                    {
                        var res = progress.ProgressPercentage;
                    });
LiveOperationResult opResult = await connectClient.BackgroundUploadAsync(CurrentFolderId,
                                                                      file.Name,
                                                                      stream,
                                                                      OverwriteOption.Rename,
                                                                      record.GetCTS().Token,
                                                                      progressHandler);
```

So question - how to make it upload files of any size, redefine timeout(currently 120s) and track progress on both Windows and WP81?

**UPD:**
I found the reason of 2 mins timeout [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.uploadoperation.aspx):

`After the connection has been established, an HTTP request message that has not received a response within two minutes is aborted.`

Is it normal for PUT request?

Comment: Can you clarify what WP project type you are using? You're talking of WP8 Silverlight and WP8.1. Do you want to get it working on WP8.1 WinRT or WP8.1 Silverlight?

Comment: Sure, I'm developing Universal app, so it is obviously WP81 WinRT.